# Sweet alert no permite la validación de los datos

Tags: php, html, sweetalert

Hice un formulario donde se permite modificar la información de un usuario, no tengo problemas con la base de datos ni nada por el estilo, todo funciona bien, me trae los datos que necesito de la base de datos y me los muestra, incluso ya tengo todos los campos validados, que no se permitan ingresar números en un campo de solo letras y cosas así.

Mi problema es que como estoy usando Sweet alert para que al momento que yo de click para guardar me aparezca una aletra de que si estoy seguro de guardar las modificaciones, hasta hay todo bien.

El problema es que cuando yo doy click en el botón "Guardar", me arroja la alerta pero no me valida los campos, podría introducir números en el campo "nombre" y no me arroja el mensaje de que en ese campo no se permiten número, y me pasa lo mismo con todos los demás campos.

```html
<form action="sig_modif.php" method="POST" name="formTest" id="formTest">

    <div class="form-row">

     <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <label for="nombre">Nombre(s): </label>
         <input type="text" name="nombre" pattern="[A-z ]+" title="Sólo se pueden ingresar letras" 
           class="form-control" required value=<?php echo $data_user['nombre']?>>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <label for="apellido_paterno">Apellido Paterno: </label>
         <input type="text" name="apellido_paterno" pattern="[A-z ]+" title="Sólo se pueden ingresar letras"
           class="form-control" required value=<?php echo $data_user['apellido_paterno']?>>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <label for="apellido_materno">Apellido Materno: </label>
         <input type="text" name="apellido_materno" pattern="[A-z ]+" title="Sólo se pueden ingresar letras"
           class="form-control" required value=<?php echo $data_user['apellido_materno']?>>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <label for="peso">Peso: </label>
         <input type="number" name="peso" class="form-control" placeholder="Kg" 
          onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' require minlength="1" maxlength="3"
           value=<?php echo $data_user['peso']?>> 
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <label for="estatura">Estatura: </label>
         <input type="text" name="estatura" class="form-control" placeholder="Cm" minlength="2" maxlength="3"
          value=<?php echo $data_user['estatura']?>>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <label for="fecha_nac">Fecha de Nacimiento: </label>
         <input type="date" name="fecha_nac" class="form-control" value=<?php echo $data_user['fecha_nac']?>>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <label for="curp">Curp: </label>
         <input type="text" name="curp" class="form-control" 
          onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90 || event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' 
                      required minlength="18" maxlength="18"value=<?php echo $data_user['curp']?>>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
         <input type="password" name="contraseña" class="form-control" value=<?php echo $data_user['password']?>>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group col-md-4">
               <label for="rol">Rol</label>
               <br>
                  <select class="form-control -lg" name="rol_id">
                    <option value=<?php echo $data_user[9]?>><?php echo $data_user[9]?></option> 
                    <?php if($data_user[9] !== 'Medico'){?>
                    <option value="Medico">Medico</option>
                    <?php }else{?>
                    <option value="Paciente">Paciente</option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
           </div>
           
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>

    <center><td>
     <form action="sig_modif.php" method="POST" name="formTest" id="formTest">
      <input type="button" name="txt_test" id="txt_test" onclick="confirmarFunction();" value="Guardar" 
        class="btn btn-success"/>

      <input type="button" name="cancelar" id="cancelar" onclick="cancelarModificacion()" value="Cancelar" 
        class="btn btn-danger"/>
     </form>
```

Al momento de dar click en el botón "Guardar" manda a llamar la función "ConfirmarFunction()" que es donde esta almacenada mi alerta.

Y este el codigo de mi alerta

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

   function confirmarFunction() {
     Swal.fire({
       title: "Confirmar",
       text: "¿Seguro que desea guardar los cambios?",
       showCancelButton: true,
       confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
       cancelButtonColor: '#f7505a',
       confirmButtonText: "Aceptar",
       cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
       showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
       showCloseButton: true
  
     }).then(function(isConfirm) {
      if(isConfirm.value){
         $('#formTest').submit();
      }
     });
 }
  </script>
```

Y como dije, no tengo ningún problema con la base de datos, de hecho doy click en guardar y se guardan las modificaciones en la base de datos, el único problema es que no me valida los campos cuando doy click en "Guardar".

Agradecería enormemente cualquier ayuda.

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes la función que valida los campos y cuando la llamas?

Comment: En los mismos input de los formularios tengo las validaciones, las hago con el pattern, max y min length y el onkeypress

Answer (score 1):

No puedes anidar fomularios, por eso no funciona correctamente al hacer clic en el botón, pero sí cuando intentas llenar los campos:

```
<form action="sig_modif.php" method="POST" name="formTest" id="formTest">

                <div class="form-row">

                    <form action="sig_modif.php" method="POST" name="formTest" id="formTest">
                        <input type="button" name="txt_test" id="txt_test" onclick="confirmarFunction();" value="Guardar" 
                                class="btn btn-success"/>

                        <input type="button" name="cancelar" id="cancelar" onclick="cancelarModificacion()" value="Cancelar" 
                                class="btn btn-danger"/>
                    </form>
```

Solución: Quita las etiquetas de formulario al final, dejando solo los botones:

```
<form action="sig_modif.php" method="POST" name="formTest" id="formTest">

                <div class="form-row">

                        <input type="button" name="txt_test" id="txt_test" onclick="confirmarFunction();" value="Guardar" 
                                class="btn btn-success"/>

                        <input type="button" name="cancelar" id="cancelar" onclick="cancelarModificacion()" value="Cancelar" 
                                class="btn btn-danger"/>
```

Adicionalmente, te recomiendo usar el evento onsubmit del form en lugar del onclick en el botón.